# Magento 2: Implementing module with cli

Tags: magento2, cli, command-line, slider

I'm trying to implement a banner slider without Commands

I have already pasted the folder into public_html/app/code/

And I created a PHP file in public_html and tried to run it but nothing happens

Can someone help me?

slider: https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-banner-slider

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Running commands to register and install a module is a must (compulsory),
you cannot skip it.

If you do not have access to ssh, you can try using php's system function to do the job.

Make a file with a secure name (so anyone else cannot hit it) at magento's root and paste following code in it;

```
<?php

echo system("php bin/magento setup:upgrade");

?>
```

and hit the file with running url `your_base_url/you_php_file_name.php`

You can replace whatever command you want in the system function.

Feel free to ping me in case of confusion.

**EDIT :**

Please note that I do NOT recommend this method as SSH is required for any kind of development in magento 2. This is for, you know something is better than nothing kind of situations.

Comment: the root folder is the public_html ?

Comment: no, I was referring to magento's root, inside the folder where magento is installed.

Comment: This is a shared host im in FTP connection right now

Comment: I don't think it will cause problem, you've to just make a file and upload it to root.

Comment: The output is " Whiios, our bad... the page you requested was not found, etc "

Comment: Note that I have asked you to name file so anyone else can't guess it. Make it some random gibberish file name.

Comment: I did it, the name is random

Comment: Hmmm.. that will be a problem. I think your site has been customised using htaccess or server side rewrites to direct all requests to magento.

Comment: You should ask for ssh, it is safer option too.

Comment: The company of domain doesn´t work with SSH ...

Comment: If magento, you should have SSH acces, Without SSH access /terminal you cannot do not  anything.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download the package from [Mageplaza-Github](https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-banner-slider)
2. Go to you project then copy the files package in :

   > app/code/Mageplaza/BetterSlider/
3. Create `launcher.php` in your root project with this content:

   ```
    system('php bin/magento setup:upgrade');
   ```
4. Call that launcher like this : `www.domaine.com/launcher.php`

Comment: didn´t work-----